# Spark Kafka Source and Confluent Monitoring Interceptor

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, interceptor, spark-structured-streaming

When configuring spark to use Kafka as exposed here:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#kafka-specific-configurations

The spark folks state the following:

"interceptor.classes: Kafka source always read keys and values as byte arrays. It’s not safe to use ConsumerInterceptor as it may break the query."

Then i saw the following here https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/external/kafka-0-10-sql/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/kafka010/KafkaSourceProvider.scala#L307

```
val otherUnsupportedConfigs = Seq(
      ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, // committing correctly requires new APIs in Source
      ConsumerConfig.INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES_CONFIG) // interceptors can modify payload, so not safe

    otherUnsupportedConfigs.foreach { c =>
      if (params.contains(s"kafka.$c")) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(s"Kafka option '$c' is not supported")
      }
    }
```

Yes Not safe, but when one knows what he does, it can be used safely. Hence i wonder why blocking it by design and if there is a work-around ?

Comment: One workaround would be to compile Spark jar yourself with the check removed...